# Rails logs do not show anything in terminal for Puma when I try to hit the URL: localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When I do `rails s`, it successfully starts my server, and serves the page through the URL `http://localhost:3000`, but the problem is: it doesn't show any changes when I access anything from this server.

[image]

I have accessed so many pages, but still it's not showing any hint. I have restarted the Rails server, have killed all the rails servers using:

```
ps aux | grep 'rails' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9
```

Have quit and started again iTerm but nothing is helping me.

I'm using Rails 5.0.0, and ruby 2.2.3.

Comment: As a quick solution you may try to tail your log `tail -f log/development.log`

Comment: If you delete the log file, is it re-created when you start the server?

Comment: @MickSharpe `logs/development.log` is re-created after deleting it, and starting the server again, but still nothing changes for `rails s`'s logs.

Comment: try to change access rights `chmod -R 777 logs/`

Comment: What do you mean by "rails s's logs"? What is the content of development.log?

Comment: @MickSharpe development.log gets updated when I request a page. *rails 's logs*: means the logs that appear in terminal screen. Makes sense?

Comment: @shilovk `chmod -R 777 log/` didn't help either.

Comment: Try 'rails s Puma'

Comment: @MickSharpe Tried, but result is same as old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem in config/puma.rb file, and it took me a night to figure this thing out. Anyway, the correct configuration for Puma while running your server for development is:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. There was an error in puma.rb file and I figure out the problem by copying following content in puma.rb file. After that, restart your server and you can now find logs on any request on the server and also stop breakpoint on the server by mentioning breakpoint in you code, which was not possible with previous configuration.

```
# Code goes here
workers 2

# Min and Max threads per worker
threads 1, 6

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env

# Set up socket location
bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"

# Logging
stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `development.rb` file. I have my app on Rails 6.

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, thanks to @mick comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335564/rails-logs-do-not-show-anything-in-terminal-for-puma-when-i-try-to-hit-the-url#comment66005263_39335564) my logs started appearing when I ran it through `rails s` (precisely `bundle exec rails s`).

I will update this answer later after debugging more on why is there a different, but a hunch is that running it through rails s would configure the logs output to be routed to STDOUT when the server is not running in daemonized mode.